# JSON escape child block content for ajax requests

Tags: php, json, ajax, symfony, twig

Every page can be served in two ways - an "html" and a "json" way.
The "html way" contains a full fledged html page - header/footer/menu/main content - just like every page.
The "json way" contains only the page-specific things, like the content and the title.

To achieve this, in every template I extend from `base.html.twig` that contains the following lines:

```
{% extends app.request.isXmlHttpRequest()
    ? "base/ajax.json.twig" 
    : "base/full.html.twig" %}
```

`full.html.twig` is just a file that wraps the content within header/footer/menu.
`ajax.json.twig` contains this:

```
{
    "title": "{% block title %}{% endblock %}",
    "content": "{% block body %}{% endblock %}"
}
```

The idea with all this stuff is to easily create flexible pages that can be served both as html page and an json reponse depending on `app.request.isXmlHttpRequest()`

The problem is that in base/ajax.json.twig I have to escape the content in the `body` block so that the file is a valid json object, e.g. `<a href="/">` makes it invalid json because the quotes are not escaped:

```
{ "content": "<a href="/">" }
```

I need something like `{{ parent()|json_encode() }}`, not with `parent()` but with `child()`, that unfortunately I couldn't find in the docs.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call block as function from layout. In your case layout will look so:

```
{% set tmp = {title:block('title'), content:block('body')} %}
{{ tmp|json_encode }}
```

Comment: if you want to replace `...|replace({'"':'\\"'})`, but also you should replace `\\`, may be new lines..

Comment: No no, my mistake, I haven't understood your answer properly... Actually I have to use `{{ tmp|json_encode|raw }}`, because twig automatically escapes html characters... Testing it now...

Comment: It works really well (at least on small pages), thanks.